# JSTL : Find the total of size of two lists

Tags: jsp, servlets, coding-style, jstl

I have two lists on a page and showing combined size of these two lists.

Here is my code

```
<c:set var="totalAvailableVehicles" value="${fn:length(searchResult.availableVehicleList)}"/>
<c:set var="totalUvailableVehicles" value="${fn:length(searchResult.unavailableVehicleList)}"/>
<c:out value="${totalAvailableVehicles + totalUvailableVehicles}"/></strong> record found matching your search criteria</p>
```

Is there any better way to achieve same without writing custom tag/functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with a "better way". This looks perfectly fine. You could also do it without `<c:set>`:

```
<strong><c:out value="${fn:length(searchResult.availableVehicleList) + fn:length(searchResult.unavailableVehicleList)}"/></strong> record found matching your search criteria</p>
```

However, whether that's better readable/maintainable is questionable.

You could also move that to a getter method of the `SearchResult` bean:

```
public int getTotalResultSize() {
    return availableVehicleList.size() + unavailableVehicleList.size();
}
```

with

```
<strong>${searchResult.totalResultSize}</strong> record found matching your search criteria</p>
```

Note that the `<c:out>` is not necessary here (it'll work as good in JSP 2.0 and newer). The benefit of `<c:out>` is the HTML-escaping of user-controlled input in order to prevent XSS attacks, but since it concerns here non-user-controlled input of type `int`, there is really no XSS attack risk.

After all, it really doesn't matter as long as you end up with a degree of readability/maintainability which your team agrees in.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, I earlier tried same and was getting `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/searchCarsResult.jsp(310,18) "${(fn:length(searchResult.availableVehicleList) + fn:length(searchResult.availableVehicleList)}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: ${(fn:length(searchResult.availableVehicleList) + fn:length(searchResult.availableVehicleList)}` It was a typo.